# MongoDb 2.6 issue with archiving

Tags: database, mongodb, bash

good day, i stuck with script which is made to backup a collection of mongodb, 2.6 version doesn't support --gzip suffix, is there a way how to use other way to archive collections and in case of need safely to do mongorestore? Thanks a lot for a reading my post.

```
#specify collections
collection_list="students loans.lib help.archive"
#if its running on local machine:
host="127.0.0.1"
port="27208"
#where to dump:
out_prefix="/apps/mongodb/uni/backup/mongodump"
for collection in $collection_list; do
        echo $collection
        out_dir="${out_prefix}/${db}_${collection}.$(date +%Y.%m.%d)/"
        mkdir -p ${out_dir}
        /apps/mongodb/server/2.6.2/bin/mongodump -u  -p --host $host --port $port -d $db --collection $collection --out ${out_dir}
done
```

--gzip is not recognized :(
P.S. I'm not able to upgrade our old university mongodb, we dont have a budget for it.

Comment: /apps/mongodb/server/2.6.2/bin/mongodump -u  -p --host $host --port $port -d $db --collection $collection --gzip --out ${out_dir} ;- i tried to put it there but mongodump says that command not recognized, thanks for commenting in my post a lot

Comment: the issue that old version of mongodb doesnt support --gzip flag and its not able to archive, and im asking if there any way how to archive this collections? thanks a lot

Comment: The script in your question appears to create DB dumps; it doesn't *compress* them, apparently because it's not a supported flag. Are you asking how to compress the resulting dumps?

Comment: yes in a way to secure to unzip them inside one script. Sorry I just started to write bash scripts, and for me some legacy is a pain :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to compress on the fly without the "--gzip" option introduced in mongodb 3.2 , you can do as follow in linux:

```
 mongodump -d yourDB -c yourCOL -o - | gzip > yourDByourCOLdump.gz
```

to restore it , you can do:

```
 gunzip yourDByourCOLdump.gz
 mv yourDByourCOLdump yourDByourCOLdump.bson
 mongorestore -d yourDB -c yourCOL yourDByourCOLdump.bson
```